# Android getSimOperator() crashes on missing permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

When running the following code:

```
try {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) MainApplication.getAppContext()
                                                                          .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String simMCCMNC = telephonyManager.getSimOperator();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Crashlytics.logException(e);
}
```

The app crashes with the following log:

> Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires
>   READ_PHONE_STATE: Neither user 10076 nor current process has
>   android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
>          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
>          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
>          at com.android.internal.telephony.ISub$Stub$Proxy.getActiveSubscriptionInfoForSimSlotIndex(ISub.java:459)
>          at android.telephony.SubscriptionManager.getDefaultSmsSubId(SubscriptionManager.java:910)
>          at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getSimOperatorNumeric(TelephonyManager.java:1622)
>          at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getSimOperator(TelephonyManager.java:1592)
>          at com.myapp.app.ApplicationInitializer.generateBaseUrl(SourceFile:297)
>          at com.myapp.app.ApplicationInitializer.initFailProofComponents(SourceFile:193)
>          at com.myapp.app.ApplicationInitializer.prepareManager(SourceFile:121)
>          at com.myapp.managers.base.BaseManager.prepareManagerIfPossible(SourceFile:43)
>          at com.my.app.ApplicationInitializer.init(SourceFile:137)
>          at com.my.app.MainApplication.onCreate(SourceFile:23)
>          at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4628)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:947)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742)

Looking at the source code for Android [getSimOperator()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java#TelephonyManager.getSimOperator%28%29). I do not understand how the code can crash on a permission which is not required for this method?

I was able to reproduce when calling [getDeviceId()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java#TelephonyManager.getDeviceId%28%29) because it requires READ_PHONE_STATE.

I've only seen this happen on android version 5.1.

Comment: can it be that all clients throwing that exception are rooted?

Answer (score -2):

Use this method its work fine

```
DeviceInfo deviceInfo = new DeviceInfo();
        TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        deviceInfo.setDeviceId(Util.getDeviceID(mContext));
        if(tMgr!=null)
        {
            String simSerialNumber=tMgr.getSimSerialNumber();
            if(simSerialNumber!=null) {
                deviceInfo.setSimOperator(tMgr.getSimOperator());
                deviceInfo.setSimCountryIso(tMgr.getSimCountryIso());

                deviceInfo.setSimSerialNumber(simSerialNumber);
                deviceInfo.setSimOperatorName(tMgr.getSimOperatorName());
                deviceInfo.setSimNetworkOperator(tMgr.getNetworkOperator());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why would this work? you havn't changed anything and you're still calling tMgr.getSimOperator()

Comment: Provide this permission in manifests Like this code   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

Comment: Why it works perfectly fine on all the devices in the office and the documentation doesn't request this permission in order to call this method.

Answer (score -2):

Use below method

```
 TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String carrierName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+carrierName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

You can retrive selected sim operator name...

Comment: I want to understand why this crashes when the permission is not even required according to the documentation.

Comment: This is actually a different method which returns an entirely different string

Comment: I did it without permission

Comment: Me too on all of the devices we have in the office. But when we released it, it seems to crashing on certain devices.